# Is there any better way to access twitter streaming api through python?

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I need to fetch twitter historical data for a given set of keywords. Twitter Search API returns tweets that are not more than 9 days old, so that will not do. I'm currently using Tweepy Library (http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/) to call Streaming API and it is working fine except the fact that it is too slow. For example, when I run a search for "$GOOG" sometimes it takes more than an hour between two results. There are definitely tweets containing that keyword but it isn't returning result fast enough.

What can be the problem? Is Streaming API slow or there is some problem in my method of accessing it? Is there any better way to get that data free of cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far back do you need?  To fetch historical data, you might want to keep the stream on indefinitely (the stream API allows for this) and store the stream locally, then retrieve historical data from your db.

I also use Tweepy for live Stream/Filtering and it works well.  The latency is typically < 1s and Tweepy is able to handle large volume streams.

Answer (score 0):

streaming API too fast you get message as soon as you post it, we use twitter4j. But streamer  streams only current messages, so if you not listening on streamer the moment you send tweet then message is lost.